# AngularJs using new Image() for jsPDF usage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, jspdf

Don't let the title scare you because I think this is an easy one. However, I am not very familiar with AngularJs (first version) so I stumble upon this basic issue.

So basically I am inside a controller and I am trying to create an image with this code:

```
var img = new Image();
    img.src = "logo.jpg";
    img.onload = function() {
        // execute some code here to insert this image in a pdf
    }
```

If you wonder why I need this, the simple answer is that I need this image to add it into a pdf via jsPDF library.

Before jumping to the part which does not work as expected I like to say that I have tested this block of code into a clean react app and it worked just to keep everything clean regarding the validity of this code.

And now, let's talk about the issue. The issue is that somehow my image is empty like the src location is not good. It is true that the project has a very complex structure and I am not very sure where it expects to find this image.

So after trying to guess the path for several hours I tried the ultimate solution which was to set the path simply the name of the image and copy/paste that image basically in every folder of the project just to see that it appears and after that to remove image by image until it won't work again in order to find out at what location it is looking. But unfortunately this approach was not successful because the image remained black/white. And here I am trying to seek an answer to you.

Before closing I just want to say that even in the react app I was using this code inside `/src` folder while the images was placed inside `/public` folder which was on the same level as the `/src` folder. So I guess that even on this AngularJs project is something like this, it looks in some place for it. I see now that I have placed it even in the `target` folder but it's not working. Any idea how to fix this ? Thx

Comment: As I said. I tried exactly this approach in a clean react app with a simple structure and it worked perfectly. This issue is not related to jspdf, its an issue on angularjs. The jspdf was just a small refeerance but it has nothing to do with that. The image dont have a source